# spring-data-flow task example

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I'm using spring-cloud-dataflow with taskcloud module but I've some trouble to lunch a simple example in container.
[tiny example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) 6.3 writing code then I've deploy it
but when I try to execute it throw me an

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid TaskExecution, ID 1 not found
>   at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:134)
>   at org.springframework.cloud.task.listener.TaskLifecycleListener.doTaskStart(TaskLifecycleListener.java:200)
> ```

In my evaluation I've used [Spring boot example](https://web.archive.org/web/20170303080751/https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-batch)
and for run in scd I've add @EnableTask and configured ad sqlserver datasource but it doesn't works.

I'm insisting on using spring cloud data flow cause I've read that spring batch admin is at end-of-life, but 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT works
well and a tiny examples works as opposed to what happens in spring cloud data flow with @task annotation.

Probably is my  misundestand but could you please provide me a tiny example where or address me some url ?

Comment: Have you tried any of the samples from here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/tree/master/spring-cloud-task-samples/

Comment: Yes, using version 1.2.1 and master changing datasource in both cases are KO instead using only spring boot is ok

Answer (score 1):

Referencing https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-rdbms, datasource arguments has to be passed to the data flow server and data flow shell(if using) in-order for the cloud data flow to persist the execution/task/step related data in the required datasource.

Ex from the link for a MySQL datasource(similar can be configured for SQL Server):

```
java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local/target/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar \
    --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql:<db-info> \
    --spring.datasource.username=<user> \
    --spring.datasource.password=<password> \
    --spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: I have fixed the same issue by getting SCDF source code & added oracle dependency jars and ran the command same as above. It worked. You need to make sure that you added drivers for DB in SCDF before running the above command. SCDF comes with DB related jars but if you are using oracle or some third party you need to add it manually. @fbalicchia

Answer (score 1):

This error:

> Invalid TaskExecution, ID 1 not found

Can be about the SCDF's datasource, in general, SCDF cannot find the Task Execution table in **its own database**, not application database

You might fix it by adding database driver or fixing url connection string, point to SCDF's database

This issue below might help

[How to properly compile/package a Task for Spring Cloud Data Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62887534/how-to-properly-compile-package-a-task-for-spring-cloud-data-flow/68601723#68601723)